# accessing arrays within an array laravel 5.6

Tags: php, arrays, laravel-5.6

My front end made with Vue.js passes the `user_id`,`paper_id` in one array, while the `answers` are passed in the second array. Both these arrays are stored within an array. the `dd()` of my array is

```
array:2 [
 0 => array:2 [
  0 => 7
  1 => 3
]
 1 => array:4 [
  0 => 2
  1 => 2
  2 => 3
  3 => 4
 ]
]
```

can anyone explain how to actually read through the data in order to store all within the database
my database schema

```
 Schema::create('answers', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        $table->integer('paper_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->foreign('paper_id')->references('id')->on('papers');
        $table->integer('answer')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

the outcome i require is to have

```
userid,paperid,answer
3,      7,       2
3,      7,       2
3,      7,       3
3,      7,       4
```

Comment: Didn't you create it yourself? I can't help you unless you describe your db schema, models and what you expect to go where. Also for the first array you can use keys. I would recommend that actually

Comment: I would recommend making answers a json field and using casts. see my answer below for current version

Answer (score 0):

This is the quick way to do it. I would change some things like the way you table looks and the logic behind, but this should solve your issue

```
$answers = $array[1];
$data = [];    

foreach($answers as $answer)
{
    $data[] = ['user_id'=> $array[0][0], 'paper_id' => $array[0][1], 'answer' => $answer];
}

Answer::create($data);
```

Make sure you have **user_id, paper_id, answer** in the **$fillable array** in Answers model

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Indra. I changed the method that the front end sends the data so i dont get the arrays within arrays instead now sends me 2 variables and one array. it seems to be a easier fix. thanks anyway